# How can i Lock or make some indicate that the listBox is not in use while the process is on?

Tags: c#

I have this button click event code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            offlineOnline = false;
            init();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            this.Text = "Processing...";
            label6.Text = "Processing...";
            label6.Visible = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            checkBox1.Enabled = false;
            checkBox2.Enabled = false;
            numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            button6.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = false;
            listBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

I set the listBox1 Enabled to be false. But it dosn't look mice. It looks like the listBox still active but in fact the user can't use it.

What i want is some idea what to do with the listBox while the process is on ? ( When clicking the button1 ).

Comment: If i lock it then it will look like colored with gray and not in use i think. But i can't find the lock property in the run time code. Maybe i need to use something else then lock ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty: disable it and change the background colour to a murky grey.

A little less dirty, subclass `ListBox` and set the colour when `Enabled` changes, possibly based on the current Windows theme.

Comment: /agree. seems that OP is prototyping. Take babysteps. You'll have plenty of more challenges to deal with in the near future. +1